# TypeScript type of array with common Classes that inherit from same Class

Tags: typescript

I have the following example:

```
class Parent {
  foo() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  bar() {
    this.foo();
    console.log("bar");
  }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
  baz() {
    this.foo();
    console.log("baz");
  }
}

const Children = [Child1, Child2];

function someFunc<C>(children: C[]) { // ???
  const _children = {}; // ???
  for (let c of children) {
    const _c = new c();
    _children[c.name] = _c;
  }
  return _children;
}

const instances = someFunc(Children); // ???

instances.Child1.bar();
```

How can I tell the `someFunc` method that its going to be expecting an array of Classes of type Children? What do I need to pass as a Generic argument to `someFunc`?

Mostly so it will know that `instances.Child1` has a method called `bar()`

Runnable: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-jackson-jnp1e

Comment: This would be simple if you were implementing a shared interface on both C1 and C2 - is this an option? because then you could just pass the interface for the generic type.

Comment: I could do this. Silly question: How would a shared interface across multiple classes that might inherit from the same class, but implement different method? ie. if Child1 had a "baz" method, but Child2 had a "test" method?

Comment: Yeah, that's the caveat where it would not work with interfaces. In the example, it looks like it would as both have `bar()`  maybe an update to the question so that child2 is `foo()` or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try `C extends new (...args: any[]) => any` for the generic type, and `InstanceType<C>` for instantiated objects present within the `_children` variable, as below.

```
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => any;

const Children = [Child1, Child2];

function someFunc<C extends Constructor>(children: C[]) {
  const _children: Record<string, InstanceType<C>> = {};
  for (let c of children) {
    const _c = new c();
    _children[c.name] = _c;
  }
  return _children;
}

const instances = someFunc(Children);

instances.Child1; // typed as `Child1 | Child2`
instances.Child2; // also typed as `Child1 | Child2`

instances.Child1.bar();
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-poitras-423fc

This is not perfect, but closer to what you're trying to achieve. One minor issue is that you can still access any key from `instances` (say, `instances.SomeUnknownClass`, which would mistakenly point to a value of type `Child1 | Child2`).

*Also* if you need the `children` argument to only allow classes `Child1` and `Child2` (or whatever your `Children` array holds), the signature of your function should rather look like:

```
type AllowedClass = typeof Children[number]; // typeof Child1 | typeof Child2

function someFunc<C extends AllowedClass>(children: C[]) {
  const _children: Record<string, InstanceType<C>> = {};
  for (let c of children) {
    const _c = new c();
    _children[c.name] = _c;
  }
  return _children;
}
```