# Array of custom forms with FormGroup as parent

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a use-case where I'm creating several custom formgroup classes that have FormGroup as their parent class like so:

```html
export class CustomFormGroup1 extends FormGroup {
  //a bunch of custom properties for this FormGroup
  
  constructor() {
    super(
      {
      // initializing CustomFormGroup1's form properties
      }
    );
  }
}

export class CustomFormGroup2 extends FormGroup {
  //a bunch of custom properties for this FormGroup
  
  constructor() {
    super(
      {
      // initializing CustomFormGroup2's form properties
      }
    );
  }
}

// etc with a couple more Custom Forms
```

What I'm trying to do is put this in an array who's type is FormGroup, i.e.:

```html
formList: FormGroup[] = [CustomFormGroup1, CustomFormGroup2, ...etc]
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```html
TS2740: Type 'typeof ResourceTypeForm' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 57 more.
```

I've found a few questions similar to my issues like:
[Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 3 more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284894/type-abstractcontrol-is-missing-the-following-properties-from-type-formgroup)
or
[TypeScript type of array with common Classes that inherit from same Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60414703/typescript-type-of-array-with-common-classes-that-inherit-from-same-class)
but none that are similar enough to my issue.

In short, what I'm asking is: Is there a way to type an array where objects in that array have the same parent class?

I do understand that I could theoretically just define all the methods for `FormGroup` in `CustomFormGroup1` and `CustomFormGroup2`, but I'm hoping there's a way I can get the desired result without having to do that.

I have also tried defining it like this:

`formArray: (FormGroup|CustomFormGroup1|CustomFormGroup2|..etc)[] = [CustomFormGroup1, CustomFormGroup2, ...etc];`

I get the same warning mentioned above.

Thank you very much in advance for any insight.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have types that are subclass of FormGroup (or FormGroup itself) in the array you can use something like:

```
formList: (typeof FormGroup)[] = [CustomFormGroup1, CustomFormGroup2, ...etc]
```

Comment: In my specific use-case, I don't want to initialize them.  Is there any way you know if to do that?

Comment: In that case you want an array of type `(typeof FormGroup)`. I edited my answer to use this.